How to include an image in pkgdown site title
I am trying to add an image .png to the title of a pkgdown site (or instead of). In quarto this is done with
navbar: logo:. I see it is possible to instert
template:  
  includes:
    before_title: <!-- inserted before the package title in the header ->

I have tried to add it with before_title: images/logo.png but no luck, any suggestions much appreciated.
